# spark times out when connecting to cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I have a lot of data in cassandra cluster with 2 node machines and 1 seed machine. I have a spark master and 3 slave nodes. Each machine is a 8 gb machine dual core. So if my data is around 2,00,000 , and when I do a rdd.count on a dataframe, it takes a lot of time and sometimes even time out.

```
val tabledf = _sqlContext
 .read
 .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
 .options(Map( "table" -> "events", "keyspace" -> "sams"))
 .load

tabledf.registerTempTable("tempdf");
val rdd = _sqlContext.sql("select * from tempdf");
val count = rdd.count.toInt
```

How can I minimize this count time?
I am ready to add more worker machines, but will it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to cache input `DataFrame`

```
_sqlContext.cacheTable("tempdf")
```

otherwise you have to transfer all data all to perform simple count.

Comment: I guess caching will request all data from the cassandra to be loaded if i am not wrong.

Comment: Caching by itself not. Any action or transformation which will use it yes. But you already transfer the same amount of rows to do a simple count.

Comment: Then will the count on the cache table incur the same time as without cache table?

Comment: Kind of. Total time of loading and counting can be higher, but count by itself should be much faster.

Comment: Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks.